# How to set up a repeated “field set” with unlimited time and event?

Tags: entities

I am planning to set up a “patient visiting record” , the repeated “field set” is time and events, for instance, “2017-12-15, the first visit, patient has stomach pain”, “2017-12-30, the second visit, patient has vomiting, has a rash on the left leg[image upload]”....every time when I click on “add item” the “time and event set” will pop up as one field. And the series “daily like” records will show on the patient record page, of course every patient will have their own page. The records of course are only accessible for admin. Is that possible to realize?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using the "double field" module (https://www.drupal.org/project/double_field) and using the "field permissions" module (https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions).

In the users' account settings add a double field, set it up as date/text combination, allow unlimited values. Use the field permissions setting to permit access to specific roles only.

This does't allow to use images to be used, unfortunately.

An alternative idea is using a paragraphs field (https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs), where you can define a paragraphs item with any fields you need. Again, set to unlimited allowed values and setting field permissions.

Comment: I’ve tried paragraphs module, it’s perfect for my task!! Thank you very much marcmueller!